# Spectral decomposition function

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, oa.operator-algebras, fa.functional-analysis

Once I met a notation of "spectral decomposition function" (for a self-adjoint operator). No definition was given. 
Could someone give me a clue what can that be, cause I can't find this exact phrase anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: Context would help here. Where was it?


Comment: University professor's lectures on operator algebras.

Comment: As you see from Robert Israels guesses, it is still unclear. Why don't you ask the professor?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this is referring to the resolution of the identity corresponding to the operator, which is sometimes called the "spectral decomposition" (e.g. in Rudin, Functional Analysis) or "spectral function" (e.g. in Akhiezer and Glazman, Theory of Linear Operators in Hilbert Space).